# Seemingly Simple js plugin for rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, alertify

I'm trying to setup [alertify](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/) in my rails project without using any gems and I'm not able to get a hello world implementation working. I've spent over half a day on this and not sure why.

In `application.js`

```
//= require alertify
```

In `vendor/assets/javascripts`

```
alertify.js
```

In front.js.coffee

```
alertify.alert "I'm an alertify alert"
```

In `vendor/assets/stylesheets`

```
alertify.default.css
```

Nothing from the console. I'm stuck, what am I missing? Having a similar problem with another plugin and I've tried calling is form the view using script tags and I get a Uncaught `ReferenceError: alertify is not defined` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem through building a simple test app - I've put [my test rails app on github](https://github.com/tessi/rails_alertify_test), for comparison.

My best guess is that the javascript in your `front.js.coffee` is executed before alertify (and the DOM) is loaded. In my case, the following worked just fine:

```
$ ->
  alertify.alert "I'm an alertify alert"
```

This compiles to `$(function(){alertify.alert("I'm an alertify alert");});`. See the [jQuery documentation for details on the `$` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).

By the way, you should also place `alertify.core.css` in `vendor/assets/stylesheets` and require it in `application.css`:

```
*= require alertify.core
*= require alertify.default
```

The later does not solve the problem you mentioned, but let's alertify look good ;)